# Grouping two arrays by their values ​with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Two or 3 ids are coming in $pks as follows and I am sending these id values ​​in sql. For example, when this for runs 3 times, total_ticket and from_user_id values ​​will come in 3 different arrays. How can I group these 3 arrays according to from_user_id value? So I want to make it into a single array

so I want to group the 2 or 3 $props returned by the value from_user_id

```
 $pks = $request->input('pkids');
        
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($pks); $i++) {
                    $pk = PK::findOrFail($pks[$i]);
                    $table_ym = date('Ym', $pk->create_time);
                    $table = 'video_' . $table_ym;
                    $props = DB::select('select sum(total_ticket) as total_ticket, from_user_id from '
                      . $table . ' where pk_id=' . $pk->prop_pk_id . ' group by from_user_id');
                    
                }
```

Comment: i don't understand, you override $props each time, why so ?

Comment: when this for 3 times, 3 arrays will be returned from sql and I want to group them @Lk77

Comment: Well at the end you only have one array, the other two are gone by then, you need to use array_merge if you want to flatten all 3 arrays in 1

Comment: What do you mean 'to group them'? What is the format?

Comment: I want to group by from_user_id

Comment: You realize that if you used  `pk_id IN (....)`  you could do this with one query and return ( presumably only 3 rows ).  Also when grouping like this `create_time` loses it's usefullness.  ie. you will have a group of records with a range of created dates.  I don't know what this `PK::findOrFail($pks[$i])` thing is but it seems your just shuffling that problem around.  PS.  your SQL is also subject to SQL injection.

Comment: I'll take care of that, but how do I group the results for the 3 id values ​​according to the from_user_id value? @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Your SQL is capable of doing that for you if you use IN with all three items from `$pks`  You'll get three rows each with a sum.  Now for that DATE it is possible to use MIN and MAX and also pull them from the DB.  `where pk_id IN (1,2,3)`.  In other words your already grouping by `group by from_user_id` but because your using only a single `user_id` you get 1 row.  Which then requires all this added complexity that is not required.

Comment: $props = DB::select('select sum(total_ticket) as total_ticket, from_user_id from '
              . $table . ' where pk_id IN (' . $pk->prop_pk_id . ') group by from_user_id'); this way it is given separately.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that if the user with 100 from_user_id has 50 tickets for the 1st incoming id, if the user with 100 from_user_id has 40 tickets for the 2nd incoming id, I want to collect

Comment: It's not quite that easy.  You need to use `$pks` as an array this would be I imagine some thing like `[123,342,1]`  (a list of product id's, no? )  so the SQL would be `pk_id IN (123,342,1)`  That will return a set of results for all users ( grouped by your grouping clause ) that have that PK ( whatever it is ) that is in the IN list.  Each with it's own SUM for that group.  Make sense.  If you only want specific users then I would add an additional IN for the user ids you want.  It's much simpler letting the DB do this.  After that it's just retrieving the rows (already grouped).

Comment: Is this `Laravel` if so you can try this `DB::table($table)->select(DB::raw('sum(total_ticket) as total_ticket'), 'from_user_id')->whereIn('pk_id', $pks)->groupBy('from_user_id')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this is all you have to do:

```
$pks = $request->input('pkids');
$pks = array_filter(array_map('intval', $pks));  //int's above 0 only

$results = DB::select('
    SELECT
          SUM(total_ticket) AS sum_total_ticket,
          MIN(create_time) AS  min_create_time,
          from_user_id
    FROM
          '.$table.'
    WHERE pk_id IN ('.implode(',', $pks).')
    GROUP BY from_user_id');
```

This will return 1 row per `from_user_id` with the `total_ticket` as that "groups" sum.  I also included the min create time which will be the lowest value of that group for that column. Or the first (earliest) created date.

All you have to do is retrive the results which should look like this

```
sum_total_ticket  min_create_time       from_user_id

    53            2022-08-20 00:00:00        1
   224            2021-08-20 00:00:00        18
```

Make sense.